# ORA-01006 with bindings within quotes

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql

I got some trouble with my bindings using `dbms_sql`. The user creates the statement and give it to may function as well as the bindings and their values. That means I know about nothing of the statement. An input could be

```
select salary from employee where name like '%:name%'
```

This raises an `ORA-01006`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491682/oracle-11g-bind-variable-does-not-exist=) leads me to the reason: the binding is within single quotes so they are treated as a literal, not a binding.

I wrote some code to adjust the statement. But it works only for the given example (`'%<binding>%'`). Is there any way (maybe using regex) to solve it for all bindings within quotes?

So if input is like `'<any pre content><binding><any post content>'` it should be modified to `'<any precontent>''||<binding>||''<any post content>'` (hope that clears my wishes).

I'm not good in using regex so my solution for the example is very unflexible:

```
l_sql := replace(l_sql, '%:'||p_name||'%', '%''||:'||p_name||'||''%');
```

BTW: I'm using Oracle 11g.

Comment: I think instructing the user to give valid SQL would be a better approach than trying to fix their sql.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance And it would be easier for me as well :) but unfortunatelly I have to assume that they won't get it correctly.

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways to screw up syntax. Trying to whack a mole their syntax errors with code to correct it sounds like Sisyphean task.

Comment: What if the user Fires DELETE <table>command. This is a very bad aproach for building any application structure. Security has to be given the utmost importance.

Comment: @AvrajitRoy The statement is checked before executed.

Comment: Does anybody see a problem using `l_sql := replace(l_sql, ':'||p_name, p_value)` and then using `execute immediate l_sql`?